How to align text in LaTeX code so that it always starts at the beginning of a line? (TeX studio)
I have the following code
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
\title{Title}
        \maketitle


                \section{Section 1}
                Some text here \\\\
                     and here.


and some text here
    \end{document}

As you can see, each line does not start at the beggining. Is there a way to align the lines like this (in LaTeX document, not pdf)
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle


\section{Section 1}
Some text here \\\\
and here.


and some text here
\end{document}

without clicking in each line and deleting the space between the text and the beggining of the line?

Any useful answer to your question will depend critically on which editor you use. Do please reveal this piece of information.

(you shouldn't use \ outside of tables and similar environments)

@Mico I am using Tex studio version 4.7.3.

Select all text and then Idefix->Unindent to move all lines to the left. Or use keyboard shortcuts: cmd+a, then cmd+[ multiple times (or ctrl+a then ctrl+[ multiple times, depending on your operating system)

Maybe try using online code formatting tools? E.g. this one: https://latexformat.com/

Instead of using your editor, you could also use latexindent -w <your filename>.tex to fix the indentation.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Idefix->Unindent works brilliant for me! This is just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

@Alezigl You're welcome!
